# Grab a slice of excel data every nth column via a callable function inside df.iloc

Tags: pandas

The following code `df_initial=df.iloc[126:236,25:28] #locate first cell` gives me a dataframe of 109rows*4columns to which I can perfrom operations.

I would like to repeat these operations inside a "for loop" for every 25+ 4th column via the df.iloc() function.

Firstly however I am not getting the location correct. my target is `df.iloc[126:236,29:32].`

My attempt `df_initial=df.iloc[126:236,lambda x:x+num:lambda y:y+num1]` where `num=25` and `num1=28` yields the following error

`cannot do slice indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.base.Index'> with these indexers [<function <lambda> at 0x00000182C0EB0EE0>] of <class 'function'>`

The problem is I dont know how to pass in  the 25+ 4th column via the lambda function...?